# Multiple upload data on codeigniter jquery using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How do I upload multiple Image files in codeigniter Framework using AJAX JQuery. I used the js file to create a simple image preview before it is uploaded and inserted into database.

my code looks like this:
**`JS :`**

```
        <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            //Check File API support
            if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader){
                var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");
                filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){
                    var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
                    var output = document.getElementById("result");
                    for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++){
                        var file = files[i];
                        //Only pics
                        if(!file.type.match('image'))
                          continue;
                        var picReader = new FileReader();
                        picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
                            var picFile = event.target;
                            var div = document.createElement("span");
                            //$('#closeImg').fadeIn(500);
                            div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                                    "title='" + picFile.name + "'/> <img id='closeImg' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/close_button.png' class='remove_pict' />";
                            output.insertBefore(div,null);  
                            div.children[1].addEventListener("click", function(event){
                               div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
                            });         
                        });
                         //Read the image
                        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }                               
                });
            }
            else{
                console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

View Part (FORM) :-

```
    <style>
    body{font-family: 'Segoe UI';font-size: 12pt;}
    #closeImg {position: relative; left: -50px; top:-115px;}
    header h1{font-size:12pt;color: #fff;background-color: #1BA1E2; padding: 20px;}
    article{width: 80%;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;}
    .thumbnail{max-height: 100px;margin: 30px;}
    </style>
    <body>
     <header>
      <h1>Ajax - File Uploads</h1>
     </header>
     <article><?php echo form_open_multipart('ajax/do_upload');?>
      <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
      <input name="files" id="files" type="file" multiple/><br/>
      <output id="result"  />
      <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" />
      </form>
    </article>
   </body>
```

CONTROLLER :

```
    function do_upload(){
      $this->load->library('upload');
      $files = $_FILES;
      $cpt = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
      for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++){
        $_FILES['files']['name']= $files['files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['type']= $files['files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['files']['size']= $files['files']['size'][$i];    
        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload();
      }
    }
    private function set_upload_options(){   
    //upload an image options
      $config = array();
      $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
      $config['max_size']      = '2000';
      $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
      return $config;
    }
```

The error does not occur but the data was not successfully uploaded.
How to add variable data on the js file and post it to the controller or another better solution to solve my problems.
thanks..

Comment: Your file field needs to be `name="files[]"` (note the `[]`) to tell PHP you're sending multiple different things with the same name. no `[]`, no sub-array in $_FILES, and you'll probably end up with only the LAST of the file inputs being processed into $_FILES.

Comment: still not working..What about variable declaration in the js file??